# PHP $GLOBALS Suggestion

Tags: php, global

I noticed Interspire Shopping Cart initializes a lot of it's classes to a PHP's $GLOBALS variable. Is there any performance or security issues when doing this?

Below is a fake file but written similar to that of Interspire Shopping Cart's.

```
<?php 
// account.php

$GLOBALS['USER_ACCOUNT'] = new USER_ACCOUNT();
$GLOBALS['USER_ACCOUNT']->createPage(); //creating the page

?>
```

I have noticed that within the process of creating the page (see above) other files that get included will need access to the $GLOBALS['USER_ACCOUNT']. So this class instance will be needed by others later down the line.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions

Comment: It's not exactly duplicate to that one above, but is certainly related.

Comment: From what I can tell of the above code, they use it as some sort of registry? It is probably safe to do so, but it is certainly not one of the best ways to do it.

Comment: @Peter, and what would you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any performance or security issues when doing this?

No, but it is a bad practice.  Storing data in the global scope *can* be a sign of bad design.  Excessive globals are a "code smell," but I'm not getting that from this specific use.

As mentioned in the comments, they seem to be abusing globals instead of [implementing the Registry pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/registry.html), which is designed to allow for exactly this type of behavior *without contaminating the global scope*.

Many other languages don't actually have a global scope for variables, meaning that they'd *have* to use Registry (or something like it) instead.  PHP just happens to make it easy to do the wrong thing.

Using a Registry rather than globals also can make it easier to perform automated testing on the code.